Java - ODataError "The mailbox is either inactive, soft-deleted, or is hosted on-premise."
I am trying to create calendar events using graph api. But on call i am getting response with an error: com.microsoft.graph.models.odataerrors.ODataError: The mailbox is either inactive, soft-deleted, or is hosted on-premise.
    private String postCalendarEventForClients(Event event, TeamsCalendarCreateRequestDTO requestDTO) {
    String caluid = requestDTO.getICalUId() == null ? "NaN" : requestDTO.getICalUId();
    UserCollectionResponse usrs = graphClient.users().get();
    for (User usr : usrs.getValue()) {
    }
    for (String clientEmail : requestDTO.getClientEmails()) {
        Event createdEvent = graphClient.users().byUserId(user.getMail()).events().post(event);
    }
    return caluid;
}


@Bean
public GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient() {
    // Create an authentication provider for Microsoft Graph API
    final ClientSecretCredential credential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
            .clientId(clientId).tenantId(tenantId).clientSecret(clientSecret).build();

    // Initialize and return Graph client
    return new GraphServiceClient(credential, scopes.toArray(new String[0]));
}

These are my app permissions

The user has assigned Office 365 Standard license in through Microsoft Admin Console. I can manually access the calendar and create events there. But the license does not appear in Azure->User->Licenses


License assigned in Microsoft 365 Admin Console


Could you confirm whether the user account is personal Microsoft account or local user where UPN ends with .onmicrosoft.com?

it is a user ending with .onmicrosoft.com

Could you check and include this image of your environment by editing your question to confirm whether the user is assigned with correct license or not? https://i.imgur.com/GjoIc4I.png

Then it should reflect in Azure Portal too like this https://i.imgur.com/xDQZ6Jh.png. Could you include complete Portal image of that user properties and licenses?

That is the problem the Azure portal is empty. https://imgur.com/LTS7ZiL

Please share that user's Overview Portal image and cross-check whether the UPNs are same for both? Check if any duplicate users available with same name in your tenant

Here you can find the license image https://imgur.com/CUIweZh .The UPN on azure is something like patrik.surname_companydisk.onmicrosoft.com#EXT#@company0.onmicrosoft.com
But email on azure is the same as on microsoft 365

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

EXT means user is external or guest user of the tenant. Check what tenant you currently signed in. companydisk.onmicrosoft.com or company0.onmicrosoft.com. Switch to companydisk.onmicrosoft.com directory and try to use that tenant app's client id and secret.

This issue was solved by registering the app on companydisk workspace instead, then the License recognized also in Azure

The error occurs if the user is guest or external user without any license in current tenant and have active M365 license assigned in main tenant.
I have one guest user without any license in current tenant but having active M365 license assigned in main tenant as below:
Current tenant:

Main tenant:

Based on below UPN, Patrik is guest or external user in company0 workspace whereas local user with active M365 license in companydisk workspace.
patrik.surname_companydisk.onmicrosoft.com#EXT#@company0.onmicrosoft.com

To resolve the error, switch to companydisk directory and register one new application in it and user that app's client ID and client secret for authentication purpose.
